# Hierarchical data and merging two data sets with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, nested-lists

I am trying to merge data from two different services calls. Data is similar in structure to this:

DTOs In Api Layer:

```
public static class GetData
{
    public record Country
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public List<State> States { get; set; }
    }

    public record State
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
    }

    public record City
    {
        // this Id is stored in Service B's DB as ItemId
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
    }

    // From service B
    public record Location
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to merge the Locations into the correct city and return the entire structure above in one shot. eg.

```
// this gets data including city (but no location) :
var country = await _serviceRequestA.GetCountryData();

// get list of Ids to make second call:
var ids = country.States.SelectMany(x => x.Cities).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

// get list of location objects based on these ids:
var locations = await _serviceRequestB.GetLocations(ids);
```

Trying to: match each City with each Location via city.Id and location.ItemId, and when found, append the location's Id, Name, Latitude, Longitude as a Location object to the City.

```
// do something like this on each city:
// ...but all previous data,
cities.ForEach(c =>
 {
  c.Location = locations.Where(x => x.ItemId == c.Id)
  .FirstOrDefault();
 });
```

But how do I take each parent object and children as-is up to and including city?

Again, my data is: `country.states[n].cities[n]`.

I'm not that experienced with C# or LINQ other than simple wheres and selects. Do I have to do multiple loops and grab each level's props and then apply the merge logic? Is there a more succinct way in LINQ?

**PS-** here is a json representation of what is currently returned from the first service call, and another with the result I want after merge. I need to append the Location object to each matching city:

```
{
  "country": {
    "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "name": "US",
    "states": [
      {
        "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
        "name": "California",
        "cities": [
          {
            "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
            "name": "LA"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
        "name": "Maine",
        "cities": [
          {
            "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
            "name": "Bangor"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So the cities will then look like this when I return data to frontend:

```
{
  "country": {
    "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "name": "US",
    "states": [
      {
        "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
        "name": "California",
        "cities": [
          {
            "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
            "name": "LA",
            "location": {
               "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
               "name": "Location X",
               "latitude": "xxx",
               "longitude": "xx-xx"
              }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
        "name": "Maine",
        "cities": [
          {
            "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
            "name": "Bangor",
            "location": {
               "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
               "name": "Location Y",
               "latitude": "yy",
               "longitude": "yy-yy"
              }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your point. `ItemId` in  `Location` is the foreign key to `Id` to `City` right? When you use  `var locations = await _serviceRequestB.GetLocations(ids); ` to get the locations, you want to add them to  the `Location` property in the corresponding City?

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct. Right now the Cities array off State.Cities just has ```id, name``` from the backend. The second call returns an array of locations. I need to link up the Locations to each city based on those ids. They aren't FKs in the DB, they are separate services and DBs. But all the City Ids will have a match in location.itemId. Basically I want to attach extra data from call two as a DTO to the correct city in each city in the list. Vs looping over the cities and making a network call for every one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and comment, I think this is what you want.

```
cities.ForEach(c =>
            {
                c.Location = locations.Where(x => x.ItemId == c.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            });
```

Or if you do not want to include `Itemid`'s value , you can also use this code:

```
cities.ForEach(c =>
            {
                c.Location = locations.Where(x => x.ItemId == c.Id).Select(x => new LocationA(){Id= x.Id,Name= x.Name,Latitude=x.Latitude,Longitude=x.Longitude}).FirstOrDefault();
            });
```

**Update**:

If you wanna access cities from country, just need to use `Foreach(xxx)` twice. Please note that if you want to output json without itemid property instead of the value of itemid is null, you need to change your code like:

```
public class City
    {
        // this Id is stored in Service B's DB as ItemId
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Object Location { get; set; }
    }
```

Then:

```
country.States.ForEach(x =>
            {
                x.Cities.ForEach(y =>
                {
                    y.Location = locationAs.Where(z => z.ItemId == y.Id).Select(d=> new {Id=d.Id,Name = d.Name, Latitude = d.Latitude, Longitude = d.Longitude }).FirstOrDefault();
                });
            });
```

Output:

[image]

You can see even the property not map a data, It will just show null.

Comment: yes, that's the idea. But here's where I'm stuck: how do I access the cities? And how to do it and keep each level's existing properties as I go down tree? I have ```country.states[n].cities[n]``` where states and cities is a list of multiple objects. Each level is an object with other properties to keep too. Once I get to the cities level with no loss within the tree, then your example should work. Does that make sense? I might not be explaining it well. I should post the example json.

Comment: I tried clarifying above. The json should help.

Comment: Please check the update, Hope it can solve your issue.

Comment: Great. I thought maybe there was a LINQ pattern that handled this differently. I will try in a few hours. Thanks for pointing out the issue with null, but we have interceptors that handle all that and the json, and it won't even show the property if it's null.

Comment: ok. If this answer can help you , could you mark it as the answer? Thank you so much!

Comment: absolutely, of course!